# Are gender roles in the workplace legal by US Federal law?

Tags: sex-discrimination

I worked two unskilled jobs, and both my employers would only assign men the most  undesirable part of the job while paying them the same wage as women.

If this practice is not legal, what are the possible claims that I can allege by *US federal law*?

Comment: I would suggest changing the title as it doesn't aswer the question you are asking in the body.   To answer the title question "Are gender roles in the workplace legal" typically the answer is no, however, some job roles can be gender discrimitory.   For numerous reasons, a white man showing up for audition to play a character who is an african-american woman won't get far in a workplace discrimination case.   While it occurs a lot in entertainment industries, this is how places like Hooters gets all female wait staff:  They cast those roles, rather than hire.  Crews are still hired by the law

Comment: You are allowed to have policies that have a discriminatory effect if they are a bona fida requirement for the job. In a warehouse, you can't say "men only", rather you can say "must be able to lift 60 lb crates for 8 hours". A greater proportion of men than women could do this task.

Answer (score 0):

Under Title VII of the Civil Rights Act of 1964, discrimination by covered employers on the basis of sex is prohibited. That would mean that you have to treat males and females identically. There is an exception for Bona Fide Occupational Qualification, and to qualify for that, the employer must prove a direct relationship between sex and ability to do the job, it must relate to the "central mission of the employer's business", and there is no better alternative.

There is no clear BFOQ pertaining to lifting, handling garbage, working in the freezers  or ejecting misbehaving guests, indeed the presumption that females are incapable of lifting heavy loads got many fire departments into trouble. OTOH, Hooters can get away with sex discrimination in hiring wait-staff, becuae that goes to the essence of their business (the same cannot be said of Denny's). De facto appearance of discrimination could emerge if employees were assigned heavy lifting jobs based on their ability to lift 100 lbs and it turned out that many more male employees could pass the test than female employees. There is no "effects test" for sex discrimination (whereby if you end up with a disparate effect on gender, that establishes discrimination). So sex-correlated distribution of jobs could arise without there being discrimination.

If there is a policy of only assigning males the jobs of bouncer, garbage technician of freezer-gopher, that would be a violation of discrimination laws. If you intend to sue, that is what you would have to prove.

Comment: Not quite sure how it works in doctrinally, as this isn't really my specialty, but there is also a distinction between which tasks within the same job description end up getting assigned to whom based upon who is present at the job site on a particular day at a particular time. For example, if a customer is being unruly, there is generally speaking, nothing wrong with assigning the task of getting that customer to leave to the sales associate who is best at that task among the various sales associates who happen to be present (not necessarily a muscle only issue).

Comment: *"Identically"* seems an extremely tight restriction, beyond even unreasonable measure. Perhaps you mean *equitably* as this matches better both the intent and letter of law.

Comment: Isn't Hooters's (potential) discrimination essentially untested, legally speaking?  They've been sued on many occasions but have always settled out of court to my knowledge.  Presumably to specifically avoid the risk of a formal court ruling against their hiring practices.

Comment: "Bona fide occupational qualifications... apply to instances in which the BFOQ is... reasonably necessary to the normal operation of a particular business.... a Catholic college may lawfully require such positions as... chaplain... to be Catholics, but membership in the Catholic Church would generally not be... a BFOQ for . . .  janitorial positions.... Customer preference can "'be taken into account only when it is based on the company's inability to perform the primary function or service it offers,' [e.g.]... where sex or sex appeal is itself the dominant service provided."-Wikipedia

Comment: @zibadawatimmy There are some cases very analogous to the Hooters case. *See, e.g., St. Cross v. Playboy Club*, Appeal No. 773, Case No. CFS 22618-70 (New York Human Rights Appeal Board, 1971); and *Weber v. Playboy Club*, Appeal No. 774, Case No. CFS 22619-70 (New York Human Rights Appeal Board, 1971). Hooters settled favorably with the EEOC on the issue in 1997. https://www.businessinsider.com/how-can-hooters-hire-only-women-2015-9

Comment: @ohwilleke Well that's a settlement on the latter point; a court didn't really rule on whether it's BFOQ argument was legitimate.  One could argue that the core business of Hooters is being a restaurant and serving hot wings, and "sexy ladies" is just an incidental of how they want to run that business, and that's usually not adequate for a BFOQ.  The Playboy Club is much more specifically selling the sex appeal and entertainment, with the food and stuff incidental to that. Hooters might prevail on the "we're selling sex appeal" grounds, but they haven't really been tested on it.

Answer (score -1):

Discrimination does not mean that there is not someone of every group or classification in certain positions.

Yes, it is illegal to blatantly discriminate against women, but the fact that the person doing certain tasks is a man does not mean that they would bar a woman from those duties.

In order to sue the company, their policies must actually prevent women from doing certain things and not just show that the person doing a certain thing was a man.

I am not saying that you don't have evidence of that, but just that the things listed in your question are only saying that men do some things, not that women are prevented from those things.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94528/discussion-on-answer-by-putvi-are-gender-roles-in-the-workplace-legal-by-us-fede).